# tsql between two dates which can be null

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, select, where-clause

I'm new in TSQL.
I need to write a stored procedure which returns filtered records.
So the user has two dates to enter. He may enter only one date, or two, or both, or any.

In stored proc I have two params @From, @To - date type.
I need to search records.

If user didn't enter dates - I don't care about dates in the select query.

If the user entered 2 dates - I need to search with them inclusively.

If the user entered @From date - I need to search up to today inclusively.

If the user entered @To date - I need to search dates less than @To.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: It's not clear if your table has one or two date columns where you want to filter on?

Comment: What would be the difference between two and both?

Comment: @MitchWheat But you are getting lot of +1.  If the question had a check you would not get as much traffic.

Comment: @Blam: that's completely beside the point. But thanks for your input.

Comment: @MitchWheat Then change your answer so I can remove the +1 and I will remove my comments

Comment: @Blam: Thank you for your +1, much appreciated. Your statement "If the question had a check you would not get as much traffic." is incorrect. Checked or not, traffic is related to how well the question/answers get indexed by search engines (and the relevancy and correctness [at least one would hope]). Also, traffic does not necessarily mean upvotes.

Answer (score 11):

```
SELECT ColumnList
FROM MyTable
WHERE
    (@FromDate IS NULL OR FromDateColumn >= @FromDate)
    AND (@ToDate IS NULL OR ToDateColumn <= @ToDate )
```

(But be aware that this can suffer from the effects of an unsuitable cached query plan due to parameter sniffing, especially if there is a large number of parameter conditions in the `WHERE` clause)

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT 
   Columns
FROM  
   Table
WHERE 
   DateColumn BETWEEN (CASE WHEN @FromDate IS NULL THEN DateColumn ELSE @FromDate END)
   AND (CASE WHEN @ToDate IS NULL THEN DateColumn ELSE @ToDate END)
```